# All of (the/a/?) time

Tags: word-choice, grammar

I've seen someone type "All of a time" before and I've often used "All of the time".

Should it be:

1. All of the time
2. All of time
3. All of a time
4. *<your answer here>*

As in:

> I make mistakes **all of the time**.

Comment: 4. Falafel time

Answer (score 5, accepted):

"All of the time" is correct, but the more commonly used version is "**all the time**" ([dictionary reference](http://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/all+the+time)).

"All of time" would be wrong in this context, but "for all of time" can be used to mean [forever](http://www.thesaurus.com/browse/forever) (as opposed to continually, habitually, or continuously). "All of a time" is just wrong, and I've never heard it.

Answer (score 4):

Without delving into the details of the actual matches involved, you can get a pretty clear sense of the relatively frequencies of "all of the time" (blue line), "all the time" (red line), and "all of a time" (green line) by looking at this Ngram chart for the years 1980–2008:

[image]

To the extent that "all of a time" is used at all, I suspect that it does so through the influence of the not-very-similar phrase "all of a sudden." Here is the corresponding Ngram chart for the alternatives "all of the sudden" (blue line), "all the sudden" (red line), and "all of a sudden" (green line) for the period 1980–2008:

[image]

Unmistakably, the dominant phrasings are "all the time" and "all of a sudden." But *constantly* is far more common than "all the time," and *suddenly* beats "all of a sudden" all hollow, so you can switch to one of those words if you can't remember which phrase starting with "all" is most popular.